# Python DataFrame - deleting rows with column values belonging to lists of values

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution to the following problem.
There's a DataFrame:

```
data = np.array([['', 'col1', 'col2'],
                ['row1', 1, 2],
                ['row2', 3, 4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:], index=data[1:,0],columns=data[0,1:])
```

I wish to retain rows in which, for example, value in column col1 belongs to a list [1, 2] while value in column col2 belongs to a list [2, 4]. 
This is what I thought would work

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].isin([1,2]) & df['col2'].isin([2,4])]
```

However `df1` prints as an Empty DataFrame. 
On the other hand, this approach

```
df1 = df[(df.col1 in [1,2]) & (df.col2 in [2,4])]
```

results in

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.
```

It would be expected to get a DataFrame with row1 in it.
Needless to say I am relatively new to Python. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your problem is that the columns are of `object` dtype (because you initially had a NumPy array mixing strings and integers). For instance `df = df.astype(int)` and your query will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert numeric series to numeric types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:].astype(int),
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df1 = df[df['col1'].isin([1,2]) & df['col2'].isin([2,4])]

print(df1)

      col1  col2
row1     1     2
```

Your code does not work because your initial `data` array is of type `object`, representing pointers to arbitrary types. Pandas does not apply conversion implicitly as this would be prohibitively expensive in most situations.

If you *already* have a constructed Pandas dataframe, you can apply numeric conversion as a separate step:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

Or, to convert only specified series:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your colunm type is `object` , since you create the data by using `np.array` , `np.array` only allow single `dtype` in each array

```
df.applymap(type)
Out[139]: 
               col1           col2
row1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
row2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

Create by using this way

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4]], index=['row1','row2'],columns=['col1','col2'])
df[(df['col1'].isin([1,2])) & (df['col2'].isin([2,4]))]
Out[143]: 
      col1  col2
row1     1     2
```

Comment: Not mine but one small fix - the columns are of `object` dtype, whereas the elements inside the `object` columns are of `str` type.